# Copy a directory with all its content to another directory in batch

Tags: batch-file, copy

I'm trying to copy a whole directory to another location using batch but all I can get copied is the content of the directory and not the whole folder per se.

Can someone please help me ?

Goal:
Copy H:\source to C:\target

To look like:

> C:\target\source\

where:

```
source\    
 -> file.txt    
 -> file2.txt    
 -> folder2\
    -> file3.txt
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll offer two possible single command options.

The first is to use the [xcopy](/questions/tagged/xcopy) command, *(now deprecated)*:

```bat
%__AppDir__%xcopy.exe "H:\source" "C:\target\source\" /EHRKY
```

The second uses the [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy) command, which superceded it:

```bat
%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe "H:\source" "C:\target\source" /E
```

In both cases, if the target directory doesn't exist, it will be created.

*To find out about the options available for each command, open a Command Prompt window, and type the following, before pressing the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.
`help xcopy`
`help robocopy`*

Answer (score 0):

Use xcopy...

```
xcopy /h /e /y H:\source c:\target\
```

Options...

```
/h: Copies hidden and system files.
/e: Copies directories and subdirectories.
/y: Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.
```

Comment: Thanks! It helps although it just copies the files from source\ to target\ and I need to copy the entire source\ directory to the target\ directory.